# Windows Service - Purpose of joined thread during startup

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have inherited a windows service for which I don't understand the purpose behind creating a new thread in the startup code. Start() is called by the OnStart service method. As you can see we join on this new thread, so therefore wait for it to complete before returning.

My understanding is that any long running startup code should be moved to a new thread, but that one *shouldn't* wait around for it to complete because we need to respond to the windows service manager in a timely fashion.

Can someone please tell me; what is the purpose of the thread in this service startup code?

```
public void Start()
{
    if (MyServerState.Stopped == this._srvrState)
    {
        this._srvrState = MyServerState.Starting;

        lock (this._startStopLock)
        {
            Thread startup = new Thread(Startup);
            startup.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
            startup.Name = "Publisher Startup";
            startup.Start();
            startup.IsBackground = true;
            startup.Join(SYSRESPONSE_INTERVAL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be a thread, but as you say, you probably shouldn't be calling .Join().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Startup.Join should not be there, as you correctly said the service startup should be completed as soon as possible. Your above code could be working probably because SYSRESPONSE_INTERVAL may be less than 30 sec (the time which service console give to startup thread to complete). Your code should run fine even if you remove the Join.